# Predict probability of failure in R using survreg

Tags: r, survival, weibull-distribution

I am fitting a weibull model as follows:

```
s <- Surv(DFBR[,"Time"],DFBR[,"Censor"])

wei <- survreg(s~ Group+ UsefulLife, data = DFBR, dist="weibull")
```

How can I predict the probability of failure in next 10 days, for a new data with group =10 and usefuleLife =100

Comment: Type ?summary.survfit to find out.  Better R practice to define s as with(DFBR, Surv(Time, Censor)).  Always  note which package(s) you are using, in this case survival.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R, but w/o a reproducible example.

Comment: I think there's both a statistical and a coding side to the question, so I think it's potentially on topic