# Exponential survival model using psm in rms package

Tags: r, survival, predictive-models

I would like to run an exponential survival model using the `psm` function in `rms` package, but I am still trying to understand the estimates, and how to obtain them. Using the `colon` data, say I would like to assess the risk of getting colon cancer for different treatment groups (Obs, Lev and Lev+5FU), while adjusting for age and sex.

### Fit

[image]

```
# datadist is needed to fit the models:
dd <- datadist(colon)
options(datadist="dd")

fit <- psm(Surv(time,status)~rx+age+sex, data=colon, dist="exponential", x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
fit
summary(fit)
# Effects              Response : Surv(time, status) 
# 
# Factor               Low High Diff. Effect   S.E.     Lower 0.95 Upper 0.95
# age                  53  69  16    0.027584 0.045310 -0.061281  0.11645   
# Survival Time Ratio  53  69  16    1.028000       NA  0.940560  1.12350   
# sex                  0   1    1    0.038055 0.066053 -0.091492  0.16760   
# Survival Time Ratio  0   1    1    1.038800       NA  0.912570  1.18250   
# rx - Lev:Obs         1   2   NA    0.034201 0.076873 -0.116570  0.18497   
# Survival Time Ratio  1   2   NA    1.034800       NA  0.889970  1.20320   
# rx - Lev+5FU:Obs     1   3   NA    0.490290 0.083921  0.325700  0.65488   
# Survival Time Ratio  1   3   NA    1.632800       NA  1.385000  1.92490
```

In the `summary(fit)`, I understand that the `exp(beta)` (here `exp(Effect)`) is the survival time ratio, and not the hazard ratio. The survival time ratio for the "Lev+5FU" group compared to the reference group is 1.632800 (i.e. exp(0.490290)); hence, my interpretation is that individuals in the "Lev+5FU" group have an expected survival time approximately 1.632800 times longer than those in “Obs” group. Alternatively, being in the “Lev+5FU” increases the time to colon cancer by 63%, as compared to “Obs” group.
To obtain the hazard ratio this would be taking exp(-0.490290) = 0.612. So patients in the "Lev+5FU" has lower risk of getting colon cancer as compared to “Obs” patients.
**Question(1): is it possible to change the code to output hazard ratios instead?**

### Model diagnostics

**Question(2): do you look at the raw data, e.g. Kaplan-Meier (KM) Curves or look at the residuals to assess whether exponential survival model is appropriate?**

### Plot

```
survplot(fit, rx)
```

Running the code gives a plot of estimated survival curves (below) for different treatment groups. **Question(3): How can I revise the code so that I can get the cumulative incidence curve instead?**
[image]

### Other estimands (Median and Incidence rate)

I tried to get the median survival time and followed the solution [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107901/conditional-expected-lifetime-in-survival-analysis/108163#108163) but the 2nd line of code gives an error. **Questions(4): How to solve this?**

```
QFUN <- Quantile(fit)
pred.med.surv <- QFUN(predict(fit, type = "lp")) 
# Error in exp(lp) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

It works for Weibull distribution. **Question(5): But how do I understand the results, why are there predicted median survival for each observation? How do I then get the predicted median survival for each group instead?**

I understand that the estimated hazard is the # colon cancer / # total individuals i.e. incidence rate. Also, hazard is 1/mean. **Question(6): How do I obtain the incidence rate per 1000 person-years.**

Thanks for reading this question. I appreciate any replies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll deal with three question.  The exponential distribution is one of those distributions that intersects accelerated failure time models and proportional hazards models.  The mean survival time in an exponential distribution is simply the reciprocal of the (constant) hazard rate.  So the summary table above is given you both.

As shown [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/psmcase) one of the best and most rigorous ways to assess the distributional assumption of parametric survival models is to compare the theoretical distribution of residuals to the Kaplan-Meier estimate of the (right-censored) distribution of residuals.

Regarding using the `Quantile` function to derive an R function that converts the linear predictor into an estimated quantile, `Quantile` returns a function that can evaluate all quantiles.  For the median you need to request the particular quantile you want (0.5).  The link above has an example of the code you need.